# I need assistance with this python function

Tags: python-3.4

I am trying  to Implement the function makeNeg() that takes a list of numbers and a number representing an index as a parameter and changes the list item at the specified index to be negative. If the number at the specified index is already negative, the function shouldn't change the list. The function should verify that the index is correct for the list. If the index isn't valid for the list, the function shouldn't change the list.

I have been trying to solve this problem but I can not find the way to start it. Can someone guide me in the right direction? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Should the function throw an exception if the index is out of bounds? Normally. you wouldn't check the index, and just let the `list` throw `IndexError` for you if a bad index is passed.

Comment: if the index is out of bounds it should send a string message saying ('That index is invalid. The list was not changed')

Comment: "Send" a string "message"? As in `print`? `return`? Both of those are generally considered poor form (exceptions are _the_ correct way to handle invalid use like this in Python).

Comment: >>>lst1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: >>>lst1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]                                                                                                   >>>makeNeg(lst1, 2)                                                                                                           >>>lst1                                                                                                                   [1, 2, -3, 4]

Comment: what I posted is one of the examples I need to type in the shell after writing my code

Comment: Also it does not say if I need to print or return.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something more descriptive. *I need assistance with this* is meaningless noise (obviously you need assistance or you wouldn't be posting here) and *python* is in the tags, leaving the only relevant word in your entire title *function*, which clearly is useless. Your title should describe an actual problem or question you're asking in a way that has meaning to a future user of this site when it appears in a search result. See [[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some suggestions. Also include your efforts so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get some trouble with accessing `mylist[n]`, even after checking the list length...

First you can compare the length of the list with your index:

```
def MkNeg(mylist, n):
    if len(mylist)<n:
        print ("Error, this index does not exist")
```

The thing is, you can't access any value of a list item that doesn't exist. Even if it's in an if/elif/else position, so that it won't be executed. What I'm saying is

```
def MkNeg(mylist, n):
    if len(mylist)<n:
        print ("Error, this index does not exist")
    elif mylist[n]>0:
        #do ur stuff
```

this doesn't work, because the compiler sees a reference that doesn't exist.

That's why you need to `try` it:

```
def MkNeg(mylist, n):
    try:
        if mylist[n]>0:
            mylist[n]=-mylist[n]
    except IndexError:
        print ("Index doesn't exist for this list.")
    return mylist
```

I didn't check the length, because you will get an `IndexError` if the index doesn't exist.

What try does is trying to execute the command. If it fails, you can handle the further execution with `except`. If not, everything is fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! This helped me a lot!

Comment: Note: An alterative that avoids the need for a check is to do: `mylist[n] = -abs(mylist[n])`; by taking the absolute value, then negating it, you end up with a negative value no matter what, no tests involved.